# where can I find error code information for facebook bot send api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I am sending daily messages to my bot users and I am getting error for some users which says error messages like:

```
(#100) No matching user found
```

or

```
(#551) This person isn't receiving messages from you right now
```

but Facebook doesn't have proper error documentations for these errors..

did anyone else come across these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a bit in the bugs platform of Facebook I found some interesting threads.

#### For the `No matching user found`

It appears that the end user could have delete the thread. Which means you can push content to user anymore until he/she chat with your bot again.

The error message isn't clear at all *by the way*.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254681614897363/

> I've tested this theory on my bot and I got the behavior they described. I can push message to users who deleted the thread.

#### For the `This person isn't receiving messages from you right now`

It seems that it can be a *confirmed* bug about that. Not sure if it is really relevant regarding your error.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2031788773712021/

> I've also tested on my bot and got the same result when I block all messages from the bot.

Comment: hey thankx man your answer gave a bit clarity, Now I need to test for my bot app