# messenger bot enable push

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm working on a messenger bot, my facebook app is not public, it's in development mode.

There's 1 approved developer for this app (me) and I can interact with the bot, but when I try to use the bot to send a message (not a reply to a message or payload!) to my page_scoped ID, I get the following error

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) This person isn't receiving messages from you right now.","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"..."}}
```

This happens only when I'm logged out, when I'm logged in & the messenger window is open I receive the message. I don't need to send a message to the bot, the window just needs to be open and receiving works fine.

I think it has something to do with a missing pages_messaging or pages_messaging_subscriptions permission in my developer dashboard. But I can't add these permissions, because a) I don't yet have a screencast and b) I don't want an official app review or make the app public. And the only button I see next to the permissions is "submit for review".

So let's say for starters I want to send a message every hour from the bot to a certain user, no matter if the recipient is online or offline, which steps/settings are necessary for my app while in development mode?

EDIT:
**I was able to reproduce the issue:** if the user clears the chat conversation, the bot no longer can contact the user. Everything works fine, even if I'm logged out as long as I don't clear the chat. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: This is generally due to a mass amount of messages being sent and your account/bot being blocked from sending messages.

Comment: I'm aware that error code 200 normally means that blocking is involved, but I haven't blocked the bot and it's only 1 short text message saying "test", only to the approved developer of the app (me) and only when I click a button, so it can't be a mass amount of messages. The odd thing is this problem is only when I'm logged out of facebook. The moment I'm logged in it works (given I have the chat window open)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where can I find error code information for facebook bot send api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680335/where-can-i-find-error-code-information-for-facebook-bot-send-api)

Comment: @j0k no, not a duplicate. I've got facebook's error code information, I was trying to figure out why I got the error code. The example you've linked is about error code 551, mine is 200

Answer (score 0):

That is what Facebook wants, to prevent message spamming. If you are doing reminder bot, ask your users not to delete conversation.

Comment: Should be a comment!